# How do I paginate Google Fusion Tables? Particularly, how do I get the total rows?

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I'm building a tabular javascript front end for browsing my fusion table. Some of the views have filters and group-bys, and I'd like to be able to paginate the results. With other cloud databases like CouchDB & CloudMine, I can put &count=true in my request URL to get the total number of rows beyond my LIMIT. I need a way to get that number with fusion tables.

I can only think of two options, both of which are expensive:

1) Do two queries - my main query with the LIMIT/OFFSET, and the same query without the LIMIT/OFFSET, and get the .length of the second query as my count

2) Do one query with no LIMIT/OFFSET and simply work with a subset of data

Both of these options defeat the purpose of using a LIMIT/OFFSET to improve network performance. Is there any other way to get the count? I can't even do a second query with COUNT() since I use GROUP BY.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to receive the count as some kind of special parameter. So you can only do a seocond query, but there is no need to transfer the same data, just to get the count.

I'd use a query with the same `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clause, but only requesting the `ROWID`. That way only a small amount of data must be transmitted. Or alternatively you could use the `COUNT()` function and simply sum up the returned values.

If you want to further reduce network load, you only have to perform this additional query once and do all further calculation on the client side (like when your on page 3, `<count> - 3 * <no of rows per page>`, or `<count> + 1` if the users adds a row).

If your data does not change that quickly (or even only via your user interface), this should be possible. I think to run one additional query per table is not that bad.

Comment: Thanks, but would `ROWID` really save that much? My query itself only returns 2 fields per row. Also, you can't do a COUNT() on GROUP BY results, right?

Comment: Well if it saves much or not depends on the data, it's up to you to try the best solution for you. And of course you can use `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY`. This returns the count for each group, which in turn you could sum up to get a total.